# Targeting a class value that begins with a space

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors, whitespace

I want to make a CSS selector for a class which starts with a whitespace, but I don't know how. For example:  `<table class=" example">…</table>`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this (which you can't)?

Comment: @torazaburo: Probably doesn't have much of a choice. See cale_b's comment on Michael_B's answer for a possible reason why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any leading or trailing spaces in the value of a class attribute are meaningless for targeting purposes. This: `class=" example"` is equivalent to this: `class="example"`.

There is no need for a special selector that factors in the space.

*From the HTML 5 spec:*

> [**2.4.7 Space-separated
>   tokens**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-separated-tokens)
>
> A string containing a set of space-separated tokens may have leading
>   or trailing space characters.

Space characters are necessary, however, for separating multiple values in a class attribute.

> [**3.2.5.7 The `class`
>   attribute**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes)
>
> The attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a set of
>   space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the
>   element belongs to.

Comment: When you see things like that, often the HTML (including the class attribute) is like that because it is generated by a server-side script that is designed to handle and "glue" together multiple classes, and the coder didn't bother cleaning up leading / trailing white spaces.

Answer (score 3):

CSS classnames are single words; spaces just separate different classnames.

You want `.example`.

Comment: So the whitespace in the original HTML class doesn't matter, @SLaks?

Comment: While I understand what you mean, the term "single words" isn't entirely clear.  Might be good to expand a bit (hyphens, underscores, etc)

Comment: @Dumb Noob: The whitespace at the start and end of the attribute doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Whitespace at the start and end of a value for the class attribute is insignificant for the purposes of class selectors. `class=" example"` is valid HTML and equivalent to `class="example"`, `class="example "` and even `class=" example "` for the purposes of the `.example` class selector.

Therefore the selector you're looking for is simply `.example`.

The only situation where it makes a difference in selectors is with attribute selectors: `[class~="example"]` will match all of the given examples, but `[class="example"]` will only match `class="example"`. (This means, consequently, that if you have some esoteric reason to want to match the element only when its class attribute has a leading space, you can use either `[class^=" example"]` or `[class=" example"]`, but you most likely just want a regular class selector.)